# How to make my loop start and stop with key presses in python?

Tags: python, loops, pyautogui

My code will start (pressing p) and stop (pressing o) the loop once, but won't start the loop again, what am I doing wrong?

```
import pyautogui, time, keyboard

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('p'):
        print("Rodando")
        x=0
        while True:
            if x == 0:
                pyautogui.press("F7")
                pyautogui.press("F7")
                print("a")
                time.sleep(0.1)
                pyautogui.press("F7")
                pyautogui.press("F7")
                print("b")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                if keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
                    print("abortando")
                    x = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```py
import pyautogui, time, keyboard
A = False
def start_loop():
    global A
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('p') or A:
            print("Rodando")
            A = True
            x=0
            while True:
                if x == 0:
                    pyautogui.press("F7")
                    pyautogui.press("F7")
                    print("a")
                    time.sleep(0.1)
                    pyautogui.press("F7")
                    pyautogui.press("F7")
                    print("b")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    if keyboard.is_pressed('o'):
                        print("abortando")
                        x = 1
                        A = False
                        break
    start_loop()

start_loop()
```

`keyboard` module does not always work if this happens then please press the key again.

Comment: It worked!!, now i just gotta disect your code and learn what you did haha. thank you so much